# How to use ORDER BY and LIMIT with UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-order-by, sql-limit

Its straight forward. I have no multiple tables.

How can I get the following SQL to work?

"UPDATE table SET (...) WHERE (...) LIMIT 2 ORDER BY something"

Comment: Please check documentation first before you are writing a query you are not sure how to write: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Comment: what's the error msg you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keywords have to be in the correct order. Put `limit` to the end

```
UPDATE table 
SET (...) 
WHERE (...)  
ORDER BY something
LIMIT 2
```